# My render is different than what i see in the preview window

Tags: rendering

This is what I see in the preview,
[image]

But when I render, it doesn't show the stars in the background, and the surface, which I supposed to be a sphere, looks like a plane in the final render.

[image]

Comment: what is your Outliner setting? Is the Render option (camera icon) activated

Comment: You've likely hidden objects in the viewport (eye icon), but not in the render (camera icon).